# how to read binary file to c program running shell command

Tags: c, shell, binary, hexdump

In c program, i need to read a binary file on remote, so need to call SHELL command to get the file content. 
The binary file content is as follows.

```
0000000 0403 1007 0000 0000 0000 0600 0067 0000
0000010 0308 1e00 4946 494e 4153 2052 4f43 5052
0000020 202e 2020 0000 6590 5446 584c 3538 3137
0000030 3344 4e42 2d4c 3545 2042 2020 5203 9b00
0000040 1a00 0000 4a41 3052 3745 2054 2020 2020
0000050 2020 2020 3031 3231 3731 2020 f068 de03
0000060 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0000100
```

Then i call SHELL command 'hexdump file', and get the command output, found the output buffer are as follows.

```
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 34
```

part code:

```
int sock_new = setup_vmi();
...
rc = write_buf(sock_new, TYPE_COMMAND, 0, cmd, strlen(cmd) + 1); //cmd is hexdump file

...
rc = read_buf(sock_new, &type, &info, &retbuf, &retbuf_size);//retbuf is the file content
```

And read_buf is calling the follows function.

```
static __inline ssize_t
psread(
int fd,
char *buf_base,
size_t buf_size)
{
ssize_t n;
ssize_t buf_done = 0;
  again:
do {
    n = read(fd, buf_base, buf_size);
} while (n < 0 && errno == EINTR);
if (n > 0) {
    buf_done += n;
}
if (n > 0 && n < buf_size) {
    buf_base += n;
    buf_size -= n;
    goto again;
}
return (n >= 0) ? buf_done : n;
```

}

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you also post some code to illustrate what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: @KenY-N I have updated the description with part code.

Comment: Are you aware that `30` is hex `0x30` which is the ascii value of `0` digit? You receive the initial `00000000` of your file. I would guess the file is a text file holding a hexdump, not a binary file.

Comment: BTW: What is your question? Where are you stuck? What did you expect to get?

Comment: The showed content seems to be already a hexdump. If you do a hexdump on it, you get a hexdump of a hexdump...

Comment: In addition to @Gerhardh: I believe your exposed sample dump has an error: It should be `30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 34` (the `20` was missing) which would be in ASCII `00000000 04`...

Comment: I want to get the real binary content 0403 1007 ...
I thought i directly get the output of command 'hexdump file', so it is text. I know 30 represents 0 in my binary file, but i don't want to get them.

Comment: 0403 1007... is no binary content. Thats a hex representation of the binary content.